# Jupyter can't see or create new notebooks

Tags: jupyter-notebook

A python3 kernel is installed.

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list

Available kernels:
  python3    /home/jamie/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

**The problem:** When I run `jupyter notebook`, no notebooks are listed, and the "Notebook" category under the "New" action is empty.

**Things I've tried:**

- I have reinstalled `ipykernel` with pip and run `python3 -m ipykernel install --user`.
- I ran `python3 -m jupyter kernelspec install-self --user`

**Additional info:** The problem started after I tried installing ipywidgets. I ran the following commands in order:

```
pip3 install ipywidgets
jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension
jupyter nbextension disable widgetsnbextension
pip3 uninstall ipywidgets
```

Comment: Do you run jupyter as root or, any other user, maybe try removing the kernel's json file and then `sudo python3 -m ipykernel install`. It appears to be a bug or maybe a permission error

Comment: I ran `sudo jupyter notebook` and the issue persists. I removed the kernel file and ran `sudo python3 -m ipykernel install`, which moved the kernel installation location to `/usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3`. The problem persists when running jupyter notebook in normal and priveledged mode.

Comment: Update: I solved the problem by reinstalling `ipython` with `pip3`.